# Where is RDD or Spark SQL dataframe stored or persisted in client deploy mode on a Spark 2.1 Standalone cluster?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am deploying a Jupyter notebook(using `python 2.7 kernel`) on client side which accesses data on a remote and does processing in a remote **Spark** **standalone** cluster (using `pyspark library`). I am deploying spark cluster in **Client mode**. **The client machine does not have any Spark worker nodes.**

The client does not have enough memory(RAM). I wanted to know that if I perform a Spark action operation on dataframe like `df.count()`on client machine, **will the dataframe be stored in Client's RAM or will it stored on Spark worker's memory?**

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, then what you will get on the client side is an int. At least should be, if setup correctly. So the answer is no, the DF is not going to hit your local RAM.
You are interacting with the cluster via SparkSession (SparkContext for earlier versions). Even though you are developing -i.e. writing code- on the client machine, the actual computation of spark operations -i.e. running pyspark code-  will not be performed on your local machine.

Comment: Is it possible to know how much data will be stored in client machine? How to be sure that no data will be stored in client machine?

Comment: @SangramGaikwad what do you mean by "stored"? Using df.count() won't "store" anything.

Comment: df.count() is just an example. What if there are other operations like mapping RDD or selecting a column. Where would the data(on the dataframe) be present.